# How to text to an iPod

Tags: ipod-touch, messages, ios, text

(Sorry about the title, I had trouble figuring out what to name it).

Anyway, a few days ago, someone asked me if they could text me. I readily agreed but then discovered that they couldn't because if they sent to my email it went to my email.

I don't want that person's stuff in my email, I want it in my texts.

So, I did all that prefacing... All I would like to know is, what information does my friend need to be able to text me? (Yes, the person does have an Apple).

**I'm currently running iOS 8.3 on my iPod touch **

Comment: What iOS version is your iPod running?

Comment: @smoooosher iOS 8.3. I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive messages on your iPod, as long as the other person is using a device which is iMessage capable, they will be able to send you texts via iMessage.

To set up iMessage:

1. On device, go to Settings -> Messages
2. Turn on iMessage
3. Once set up, make sure you choose your email address as one that can receive iMessages (tied to your Apple ID)
4. Have friend send messages to you via iMessage as they would a normal text to one of the addresses provided in iMessage setup

More information can be found [here](https://www.apple.com/ios/messages/) and [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201349)

Comment: I think I get it 

Comment: nice that is a +, give us more of those for more (+)